# JavaScript or jQuery to select the last x letters in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

html:

```
<select id="dropdown">

<optgroup>
<option>11111</option>
<option>22222</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup>
<option>33333</option>
<option>44444</option>
</optgroup>

</select>
```

I want to select the last 4 characters of the string in every `<option>`, then style them as `color:white;`. But I still need them to be there, just that no one can see.

This is what I have:

```
let myStr = document.querySelector('#dropdown optgroup  option').innerHTML;
let lastChar = myStr[myStr.length -4];
```

it only selects the second character in the string, maybe a for loop to select all last 4?

Comment: err, why not just make the full string the value, and the text content what you want people to see?

Comment: You also know that the select-option dropdown looks different on different browsers/OS:s. Simply making them white wont hide it.

Comment: you can't style parts of an <option>, you can only style the whole thing, and even then, there's many browser-imposed styling limitations. if you want hidden data, use _data-_ attribs, the _value_ attrib, and the _title_ attrib on <option>s.

Comment: Valid point! This is working in a CMS, so I have no control over the code, the idea is for the code to do something else when one of the option is selected, so the values 11111 and so on, must be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `slice` method to select the last x characters in a string.

```js
let myStr = document.querySelector('#dropdown optgroup option').innerHTML;
let lastChar = myStr.slice(-4);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: Thank you! I tried something similar (sorry didn't mention in my post), the reason I need all the strings to be there is because this is working on a CSM, so these code are generated by the system.I'm making the page to do something once an option is chosen based on string value, so all the strings have to be there. I believe with .slice my other code like "if select value is 11111, show alert ('this is chosen')" won't work since it can't find the string value.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what one of the comments said:

```html
<select id="dropdown">

  <optgroup>
    <option value="11111">1</option>
    <option value="22222">2</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup>
    <option value="33333">3</option>
    <option value="44444">4</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>
```

Styling won't work anyway (you have very limited options styling select elements), and even if it did, making the colour the same as the background is extremely bad practice. If you must do that sort of thing in the future it's best to manipulate the element itself rather than try to hide it.

Comment: I agree, I can'r think of a way to do this with JS without shaving off part of the string, which the code needs in order for the next event. (like what I mentioned in my other comments)